# cannot POST using AJAX in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Hoping I have maybe overlooked something here. I have been looking for a bit and cannot find a solution.

In CI, I am trying to POST via AJAX in an onClick event. when triggered, the event should add an item to the shopping cart.

My Javascript is as follows:

```
function addToCart(id) {

    var productID = id;
    var qty = 1;


    $.ajax({
        url : "/menu/add/"
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        data : {"productid" : productID, "qty" : qty},
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error : function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Inside my Menu controller, the add function reads as follows:

```
public function add(){
    if (isset($_POST['productid']) && 
        isset($_POST['qty'])       &&
        is_numeric($_POST['qty'])  &&
        $this->product_model->isValidProductId($_POST['productid']) 
        ){
            $productData = array(
               'product_id'   => $_POST['productid'],
               'product_qty'  => $_POST['qty']
            );

            $cart_array = $this->session->userdata('cart');

            array_push($cart_array, $productData);
            $this->session->set_userdata('cart', $cart_array);
        }
}
```

I call the function like this:

```
<h1 onclick="addToCart(23)">OTown Cafe Menu- Click an item to add it to your order!</h1>
```

Neither the success or error is triggered from ajax, however if I put an alert before or after the ajax it IS triggered. Anyone seeing what I've done wrong?

Comment: what you return as success from controller

Comment: I see no code that calls `addToCart` ... so, not surprising it isn't called

Comment: Jaromanda X, let me update

Comment: you have to return json

Comment: @NanThiyagan the controller is exactly as I used it- this is my first use of ajax in codeigniter, so I was unsure of how to proceed, this is simply what I came up with after reading StackOverflow for a while.

Comment: `echo json_encode($data)` to get success ajax

Comment: @SivaGanesh can you elaborate onthat?

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: You are missing `,` after `url : "/menu/add/"`.

Comment: check if you're actually sending the right data to your function. add `print_r($_REQUEST); die;` just above `if (isset($_POST['productid'])` and check your console and see if the data is actually retrieved as JSON by your function

Comment: @Mr.Blue good catch. I need my glasses. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed , after url:

```
url : "/menu/add/",
```

Try this for response:

```
public function add(){
    if (isset($_POST['productid']) && 
        isset($_POST['qty'])       &&
        is_numeric($_POST['qty'])  &&
        $this->product_model->isValidProductId($_POST['productid']) 
        ){
            $productData = array(
               'product_id'   => $_POST['productid'],
               'product_qty'  => $_POST['qty']
            );

            $cart_array = $this->session->userdata('cart');

            array_push($cart_array, $productData);
            $this->session->set_userdata('cart', $cart_array);
            return json_encode(['status'=>'success','msg'=>'Message here','data'=>[]]);
        } else {
            return json_encode(['status'=>'error','msg'=>'Please send all details','data'=>[]]);
        }
}
```

See if it is work for you.

Js:

```
function addToCart(id) {

    var productID = id;
    var qty = 1;


    $.ajax({
        url : "/menu/add/"
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        data : {"productid" : productID, "qty" : qty},
        success : function(data) {
            if (data.status == 'Success') {
                alert('data.status');
            } else{
                alert('data.status');
            }
        },
        error : function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: this is now triggering, but giving the alert "[object Object]"

Comment: To add detail- using "alert(JSON.stringify(YOUR_OBJECT_HERE, null, 4));" gave me the content of the object, which is the body of my 404 page.

Comment: Ofc this is the case, you can access the individual elements in js via `data.status` and `data.msg` ... for example `alert(data.status);`

Comment: Oh but you are getting a 404?  When you make the ajax action with chrome dev tools open and network pane open in dev tools look for the name of the controller and see if its red and what the headers are...

Comment: @Alex, according to headers its actually a 500 internal error.

Comment: `index.php` change env to `development` (if remote then upload this change to server) and then run again and view contents via network > controller name > response to see cause of 500 error

Comment: I should add, the form data that we're posting IS in the headers, but I cannot see what is causing the 500

Comment: It is just saying "The action you have requested is not allowed.", is this a CSRF protection, you think?

Comment: @Alex I can confirm this as CSRF protection issue plus the corrections you'd made.

Answer (score 0):

> You are using  dataType : "json", So you have to return json

```
public function add(){
    if (isset($_POST['productid']) && 
        isset($_POST['qty'])       &&
        is_numeric($_POST['qty'])  &&
        $this->product_model->isValidProductId($_POST['productid']) 
        ){
            $productData = array(
               'product_id'   => $_POST['productid'],
               'product_qty'  => $_POST['qty']
            );

            $cart_array = $this->session->userdata('cart');

            array_push($cart_array, $productData);
            $this->session->set_userdata('cart', $cart_array);
        }
                $arr['success'] = 1;
                print json_encode($arr);
                exit;
}
```

**View**

```
function addToCart(id) {

    var productID = id;
    var qty = 1;


    $.ajax({
        url : "/menu/add/",
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        data : {"productid" : productID, "qty" : qty},
        success : function(arr) {
      if(arr.success==1){
            alert('yes');
        },
        error : function(arr.error==1) {
            alert('no');
        }
    });
}
```